# Creating donut polygon in existing polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon-creation, donut-polygons

I am tracing polygons in ArcGIS with the help of editor tool but I need to exclude some areas from the existing polygons.

How can I make it?

I went through google, but instructions provided are either not clear or i am not able to understand what they say.

Comment: Right click and hit finish part, then draw the hole, when you're all done with the hole(s) finish the sketch as you would normally do. You can use this same technique to create multi-part polygons by drawing another outside polygon, it all gets sorted when you finish  the sketch. Warning: do not cross (or touch) the boundaries you've drawn, this creates a non-simple polygon and will be rejected by some feature storage types.

Comment: For example, i have a big field area where there is a small pond. I need to know the area of field only and therefore, I need to exclude the ponds. I created the first big polygon (say field) and finished the sketch. Then I created a polygon for the pond. But what next as per your suggestions. I did not understand your suggestions.

Comment: My suggestion was to add the hole while adding the big area, now that you've finished the sketch select the big polygon, right click and select edit vertices (or just double click) then a toolbar will pop up somewhere on the screen, locate the continue feature on that tool bar and click on it, right click and select finish part to stop with drawing the big polygon now trace the lake and then F2 or right click and select finish sketch.  If you only have one editable layer you could also select the lake then from editor select clip and discard the intersecting area which will cut the lake out.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I did the much simpler way.1. I created the first big polygon. I used the cut tool and draw the polygon of the pond and finished sketching. I used the edit/select tool (little arrow next to editor drop down) and selected my pond polygon and hit delete. Now I can see the polygon excluded from the field polygon.  I think this is much simpler when you have few donuts polygons to create. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead with trace than click the last point you want to finish tracing, than click "Straight Segment" without closing command of creating feature (it is the third button in editor toolbox), than create your new area by clicking whenever you want. If you want to return back in tracing just click tracing, start new point (by snapping the old feature you wanna trace) and you are back without closing polygon.

Comment: Or create two polygons, and cut the smallest one, by tracing the smallest edge. (using Cut Polygon Tools, at editor toolbox)

Comment: That works too Florjan, just make sure the polygon you digitize closes properly.. I usually cross over the beginning/end segment (bunny ear) the hole. That method is quicker for cutting a hole out of an existing polygon than *continue feature*; have you tried Editor::Clip? it works but can have serious side-effects if you're not careful, it works on all editable layers: draw your intended hole, while still selected use editor::clip and select *discard intersecting area* from the dialog then delete the hole template you had drawn... good for cutting the same area out of many layers.

Comment: Michael, if i have just one gap i use the first away, digitizing everything and leaving the last two point not connected (because is not possible to use snap for current polygon), than after i have finished the polygon with "edit vertices" i connect last two point (a gap is created). If i have more than one i use cut method. The clip method i always test it because im not sure which polygon to chose firstly :D